# In UWP application, future.wait() keep waiting while trying to synchronize the response from async methods

Tags: c++, visual-studio, asynchronous, uwp, windows-10

I am working on developing an UWP application which would load the file from Application local data on click of a `Button`. For this, I need the `StorageFolder` object for Application LocalFolder using `StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync()` method then i will have to use `GetFileAsync()` method to read the `StorageFile` object to read.

I have written the templates to wait for the response from async methods like `GetFolderFromPathAsync(), GetFileAsync(),` etc. before proceeding.

```
template <typename T>
T syncAsyncTask(concurrency::task<T> mainTask) {
    std::shared_ptr<std::promise<T>> done = std::make_shared<std::promise<T>>();
    auto future = done->get_future();

    asyncTaskExceptionHandler<T>(mainTask, [&done](bool didFail, T result) {
        done->set_value(didFail ? nullptr : result);
    });
    future.wait();
    return future.get();
}


template <typename T, typename CallbackLambda>
void asyncTaskExceptionHandler(concurrency::task<T> mainTask, CallbackLambda&& onResult) {
    auto t1 = mainTask.then([onResult = std::move(onResult)](concurrency::task<T> t) {
        bool didFail = true;
        T result;
        try {
            result = t.get();
            didFail = false;
        }
        catch (concurrency::task_canceled&) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Win10 call was canceled.");
        }
        catch (Platform::Exception^ e) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Error during a Win10 call:");
        }
        catch (std::exception&) {
            OutputDebugStringA("There was a C++ exception during a Win10 call.");
        }
        catch (...) {
            OutputDebugStringA("There was a generic exception during a Win10 call.");
        }
        onResult(didFail, result);
    });

}
```

**Issue :**

> When i call `syncAsyncTask()` method with any task to get
>   its response, it keeps waiting at `future.wait()` as `mainTask` never
>   complete and `promise` never set its value.
>
> See below code :

```
void testStorage::MainPage::Btn_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^ localFolder = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;
    auto task = concurrency::create_task(Windows::Storage::StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(localFolder->Path));
    auto folder = syncAsyncTask<Windows::Storage::StorageFolder^>(task);
    printString(folder->Path);
}

void printString(Platform::String^ text) {
    std::wstring fooW(text->Begin());
    std::string fooA(fooW.begin(), fooW.end());
    const char* charStr = fooA.c_str();
    OutputDebugStringA(charStr);
}
```

> **Running environment :**
>
> 1. VS2017
> 2. Tried with C++14 and C++17, facing same issue.
> 3. Windows 10 RS5 Build#17763

Has anyone ever faced this issue?

Please help!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've reported it, the relevant team was investigating it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take the above code and create a simple application that reproduced this issue. Long story short, I was able to get `future.wait()` to return by telling the continuation in `asyncTaskExceptionHandler` to run on a background thread:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename CallbackLambda>
void asyncTaskExceptionHandler(concurrency::task<T> mainTask, CallbackLambda&& onResult) {
    // debug
    printString(mainTask.is_apartment_aware().ToString());

    auto t1 = mainTask.then([onResult = std::move(onResult)](concurrency::task<T> t) {
        bool didFail = true;
        T result;
        try {
            result = t.get();
            didFail = false;
        }
        catch (concurrency::task_canceled&) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Win10 call was canceled.");
        }
        catch (Platform::Exception^ e) {
            OutputDebugStringA("Error during a Win10 call:");
        }
        catch (std::exception&) {
            OutputDebugStringA("There was a C++ exception during a Win10 call.");
        }
        catch (...) {
            OutputDebugStringA("There was a generic exception during a Win10 call.");
        }

    // It works with this
    }, concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary());
}
```

Assuming the code I used was correct, what I believe to be happening is that we created a deadlock. What we are saying with the above code is:

1. On the UI/STA thread, create/handle an async operation from `GetFolderFromPathAsync`
2. Pass this task off to our `syncAsyncTask`, which in turn passes this off to `asyncTaskExceptionHandler`.

   - `asyncTaskExceptionHandler` adds a continuation to this task which schedules it to run. By default, tasks run on the thread that called them. In this case, it is the UI/STA thread!
3. Once the thread is scheduled, we return back to `syncAsyncTask` to finish. After our call to `asyncTaskExceptionHandler` we have a `future.wait()` which *blocks until the promise value is set*.

   - This prevents our UI thread from finished execution of the `syncAsyncTask`, but *also* prevents our continuation from running since it is scheduled to run on the same thread that is blocking!

In other words, we are waiting on the UI thread for an operation to complete that cannot begin until the UI thread is finished, thus causing our deadlock.

By using `concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_arbitrary()` we tell the task that it's okay to use a background thread if necessary (which in this case it is) and everything completes as intended.

For documentation on this, as well as some example code illustrating async behavior, see the [Creating Asynchronous Operations in C++ for UWP Apps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/concrt/creating-asynchronous-operations-in-cpp-for-windows-store-apps?view=vs-2017).

Comment: Yes, i got this working by adding arbitrary task continuation context but forgot to put the solution over here. Thanks for helping me out. It works!!

Comment: Glad it works! Since this is the solution, could you go ahead and mark it?